# Scala map split input to int and string?

Tags: scala, dictionary

Normally if I am reading a line of input from stdin that looks like "100 200" I can store them both as ints with this line:

```
val Array(a, b) = readLine.split(" ").map(_.toInt);
```

But what if `a` is an integer and `b` is a string?

Comment: well if the types are different you cannot store them in an homogeneous container such as an `Array`. If you know the cardinality just put them in variables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot store values of different types into an homogeneous container such as an `Array`.
If you know the cardinality, just store them in separate variables.

```
val input = "100 foo"
val Array(a, b) = input.split(" ")

val p1 = scala.util.Try(a.toInt)
val p2 = b
```

I used `scala.util.Try` because `toInt` may fail and throw an exception

Answer (score -1):

```
val readLine = "100 foo"
val (int, str) = readLine.split(" ") match {case Array(i, s) => (i.toInt, s)}
```